# countdowntimer doesn't print on textview

Tags: android, android-layout

my application is question/answer application , the user ask for a question , then the server send question to a user, when user receives the question , a ShowQuestion button appears , when user click it , i want to start timer , because a user have to answer in just 36 Second
i build a textView in my xml like this

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRemaingTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" 
/>
```

and in my Java activity i make this

```
TextView remaingTimer;
CountDownTimer timer;
private void initialize() {
remaingTimer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRemaingTime);
}
```

and when a user click ShowQuestion i make this

```
timer =new CountDownTimer(360000,100) {
   public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        remaingTimer.setText(millisUntilFinished+"");
   }
   public void onFinish() {
    remaingTimer.setText("finish");
   }
};
timer.start();
```

but it doesn't print anything, what am i doing wrong ?

### NOTE

i am using AsyncTask to get question from server like this:

```
public class getQuestionFromServer extends
    AsyncTask<String, Integer, String[]> {}
```

but i don't thing it effect on textView because the ShowQuestion button will not appear else a user have got a question from the server

Comment: have u call this method initialize() in oncreate or not

Comment: yes for sure and this is it :`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.answerquestoin);
  initialize();
  new getQuestionFromServer().execute("0999440921");
 }`

Comment: Post entire code, I tried your code it seems to be working

Comment: @iNan do u mean to give you all the activity code ?

Comment: Not all give skeleton, Are your updating textview on AsyncTask????

Comment: have set click event for ur button or not

Comment: @iNan no i don't update textview on AsyncTask, and i will give you some code now

Comment: @iNan i notice something , the textView appears while i am getting data from server, but when the data has been gotted , the text view is removed

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?9vv0ro7e1229hkd this is the activity code

Comment: @Totti Hey can you copy the timer initialization in to your function initialize, and in your onClick method just use timer.start()???

Comment: i tried that , and the textView doesn't appear, but when i put the timer initialition on iniialize() and the timer.start() in inialized too the textView appear just while the data is getting from server

Comment: put timer.start() on postExcute method in your AsyncTask().

Comment: that is wrong to but start there , because the timer have to start when the user click the ShowQuestion button , not when the client finisht get question from a server, because a user can got a question from a server but that question will still invisible until the user click showQuestion then the question will be shown and the timer have to start

Comment: @iNan it works , i just make the textView at the top of the screen

Comment: @Totti em glad finally u cud do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for updateing TextView from Thread as:

```
TextView remaingTimer;
CountDownTimer timer;
private boolean mClockRunning=false;
private int millisUntilFinished=36;
private void initialize() {
remaingTimer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvRemaingTime);
}
 ShowQuestionbutn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(mClockRunning==false)
                {
                    mClockRunning=true;
                    millisUntilFinished=0;
                    myThread();
                }
    public void myThread(){
            Thread th=new Thread(){

             @Override
             public void run(){
              try
              {

               while(mClockRunning)
               {
               Thread.sleep(100L);// set time here for refresh time in textview
               CountDownTimerActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     if(mClockRunning)
                     {
                                                                                                       if(millisUntilFinished<0)
               {
               mClockRunning=false;
               millisUntilFinished=36;
                }
                else
                {
               millisUntilFinished--;
               remaingTimer.setText(millisUntilFinished+"");//update textview here
               }
                     }

            };
                       }
              }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
             }
             }
            };
            th.start();
           }
```

Comment: thank you for helping , but why i have to user thread and there is countDownTimer (ready component) for that

Comment: @Totti : as u are saying textview is not updating.i'm given an option if  countDownTimer not work then try by  creating your own timer using Thread.

Comment: i got you , and i will try your option , thank you for helping man

Comment: i discover something in my code , while i am getting data from server the text view is updating and be shown , but when a client finish getting data from server , the textView removed

Comment: see my edit answer  and just copy past it it start from 36s and decrese to 0s but plz put some validation according to need on millisUntilFinished

Comment: i got an error on `CountDownTimerActivity` should i put the name of my activity instead ?

Comment: yes replace CountDownTimerActivity  with your current activity name

Comment: sorry still nothing appear :( :( , the is the activity code  , i wrote as u till exactly http://www.mediafire.com/?3icphtbmzeg7d2e

Comment: i mean in the code i send to you i forget to copy (th.start() ) so i told you that , please would you check my code please

Comment: @imarn , it works , i just make the textview at the top of the screen